# How to get text from an instance of a radio button class created

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jradiobutton

This code runs but the new problem is that I am able to select more than one radio button in each section which is not supposed to happen.

Also, it calculates the scores wrong. Please can someone help me fix it? Thank you!!!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class Q_Panel extends JPanel
{
   //This is the radiobutton class 

   public JRadioButton one = new JRadioButton("none");
   public JRadioButton two = new JRadioButton("none");
   public JRadioButton three = new JRadioButton("none");
   public JRadioButton four = new JRadioButton("none");
   public String answer = new String("none");

   public JLabel qLabel = new JLabel("none");

   public ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

   public Q_Panel()
   {
      group.add(one);
      group.add(two);
      group.add(three);
      group.add(four);

      QuoteListener listener = new QuoteListener();
      one.addActionListener(listener);
      two.addActionListener(listener);
      three.addActionListener(listener);
      four.addActionListener(listener);

      add(qLabel);
      add(one);
      add(two);
      add(three);
      add(four);

   }

   private class QuoteListener implements ActionListener
   {
      //When I run this I do not notice it work...
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
      {

         String selected_answer = "";
         Object source = event.getSource();

         if(source == one)
            answer = one.getText();
         else
            if(source == two)
               answer = two.getText();
            else
               if(source == three)
                  answer = three.getText();
               else
                  answer = four.getText();


         System.out.println("Answer chosen : " + selected_answer);

      }

   }
};


class radio_button
{
   //This is the the class where an instance of the radiobutton class is initialized
   public static JFrame frame;
   public static JPanel panel;
   public static JLabel qLabel;
   public static JButton Submit;
   public static Q_Panel[] qnum;
   public static String right_answer[];
   public static int Number_of_lines;
   public static String right[];



   public static void create()  
   {
      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setTitle("Sample Radio Buttons");
      frame.setSize(500, 800);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      qnum = new Q_Panel[10];
      right = new String[10];
      right_answer = new String[10];
      submit = new JButton("Submit");

      int y = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while( i < 10)
      {

        y = 60 * i;

        //We want to assume that the right answer is only "male"
        right_answer[i] = "male";

        qLabel = new JLabel ("Name of Exam file: " + i);
        qLabel.setBounds(10, y+20, 500, 25);
        frame.add(qLabel);

        qnum[i] = new Q_Panel();
        qnum[i].one = new JRadioButton();
        qnum[i].one.setText("male");
        qnum[i].one.setBounds(10, y+40, 150, 25);
        frame.add(qnum[i].one);

        qnum[i].two = new JRadioButton();
        qnum[i].two.setText("female");
        qnum[i].two.setBounds(10, y+60, 150, 25);
        frame.add(qnum[i].two);

        qnum[i].three = new JRadioButton();
        qnum[i].three.setText("shemale");
        qnum[i].three.setBounds(200, y+40, 400, 25);
        frame.add(qnum[i].three);

        qnum[i].four = new JRadioButton();
        qnum[i].four.setText("exmale");
        qnum[i].four.setBounds(200, y+60, 400, 25);
        frame.add(qnum[i].four);

        i++;  
      }

        submit.setBounds(400, y+80, 450, 50);
        final int v = 0;
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
           {
               //This is supposed to display all the text of the buttons selected and calculate the score in comparison to the right answer.. 

               System.out.println("Submit has been pressed");            

               int right_answer_count = 0;
               int score = 0;
               String answer_chosen = "";
               boolean checked = true;
               int i = 0;

               while( i < 10)
               {
                  answer_chosen = "nil";
                  if (qnum[i].one.isSelected())
                  {
                     answer_chosen = qnum[i].one.getText();
                  }
                  else if (qnum[i].two.isSelected())
                  {
                     answer_chosen = qnum[i].two.getText();
                  }
                  else if (qnum[i].three.isSelected())
                  {
                     answer_chosen = qnum[i].three.getText();
                  }
                  else if (qnum[i].four.isSelected())
                  {
                     answer_chosen = qnum[i].four.getText();
                  }
                  else if (answer_chosen.equals("nil"))
                  {
                     checked = false;
                  }

                  if(answer_chosen.equals(right_answer[i]))
                  {
                     right_answer_count++;
                  }

                  System.out.println("Answer Chosen: " + answer_chosen);
                  System.out.println("This is the answer in qnum: "+ qnum[i].answer);

                  i++;
               }

               System.out.println("I: "+i);
               System.out.println("Count right: "+right_answer_count);
               score = (right_answer_count/i);
               System.out.println("Score: " + score);

           }
        });

        frame.add(submit);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      create();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is, you've overused `static`...

You declare the `JRadioButton`s in `Q_Panel` as ...

```
public static JRadioButton one = new JRadioButton("none");
public static JRadioButton two = new JRadioButton("none");
public static JRadioButton three = new JRadioButton("none");
public static JRadioButton four = new JRadioButton("none");
```

Then in `radio_button` class you start doing things like...

```
qnum = new Q_Panel[10];

qnum[i].one = new JRadioButton();
qnum[i].one.setText("male");
```

The problem is, each instance of `Q_Panel` is using the last instance of `one`, `two`, `three` and `four`...which means if your select `one` in `qnum[0]`, all the other instances will also have selected `one`...

Remove the `static` references and modify your code to allow `Q_Panel` to manage the `JRadio` buttons.  You could even provide `Q_Panel` with a method that would return an `int` or `String` or a `enum` which described what was selected...

Comment: Thank you!!! I did as you said and added this line of code for it to work... `qnum[i] = new Q_Panel();` However, I it allows me to select more than one radio button. That I could not figure out how to fix it.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html)

Comment: In that case, what makes you think I'll explain nit any better?

Comment: There's an [example here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton)

Comment: Oh I figured out my problem earlier.. Forgot to update you. Thanks @MadProgrammer